# Logical string matching

Tags: r, regex, stringr

What is the best way to match words with my sentence? Here is a little sample:

```
words <- c("apple", "pear", "grape")
sentences <- c("I have an apple and a pear", "Grape is my favorite", "I don't like pear")
```

The best is if the output could look like:

```
count  sentence 
2      "I have an apple and a pear"
1      "Grape is my favorite"
1      "I don't like pear
```

I have tried using `str_count` but to no avail.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *How* did you try "using `str_count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
str_count(sentences, paste0("(?i)\\b(", paste0(words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b"))
[1] 2 1 1
```

How this works:

- `(?i)`: this makes sure the pattern match is case-insensitive
- `\\b` and `\\b` make sure the words are matched as words with word boundaries (if `\\b` is not used you may end up matching something that just *contains* your words but forms itself a different word such as `grapple`, which contains `apple`)
- `(` and `)`form a non-capturing group, the content of which are the `words` separated, or combined if you prefer, by the pipe `|`, a metacharacter for alternation signifying 'OR'.

If you want to have this inside a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  sentences = sentences,
  count = str_count(sentences, paste0("(?i)\\b(", paste0(words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")))
```

Result:

```
  df
                     sentences count
  1 I have an apple and a pear     2
  2       Grape is my favorite     1
  3          I don't like pear     1
```